# ACCESS- COUNTING #of data Containing specific words

Tags: sql, ms-access

I got some data and would like to count how many of them contain my word list.

For example, First set contain following:

```
A hello world
B world hi
C hi hi
D global hello
E hello universe
```

AND second set:

```
A hello
B world
```

And then,

```
A **hello** **world**
B **world** hi
C hi hi
D global **hello**
E **hello** universe
```

Thus, expected output should be -

```
A, 
B, 
D, 
E
```

4 data

Please help me how can I do this in Access.
Its quite huge data.
Help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Next time Please include an example of the code you have tried and a better description of your problem.  That said if you only have a few items in your word list(better description) use a calculated field based on DCount.  Google Calculated Field and DCount.

Comment: Thanks! but I got quite a large amount of data on both sides. 1GB csv/5mb txt Do you have any idea towards this?

Comment: Access is not the best tool to deal with huge data. Why do you want to do it there? Is it kind a challenge?

Comment: yes, I would put the Dcount code in a public function getWordCount.  Access intellisense can find public functions so you can use them in your queries.  If you always have the same number of words in your word list(better define problem) then create a query joining your data to your word list and add a WordCount calculated variable that now has access to everything it needs.  WordCount: getWordCount(worda, wordb, wordc)

Comment: Your expected output is not a count as the title states. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
select count(*)
from table1 as t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 as t2
              where instr(t1.col, t2.word) > 0
             );
```

Note:  This answers the question you asked here.  But it does not take word boundaries into account.  If that is an issue, ask a *new* question.